# Greatest timestamp per group

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

I have a fairly simply tabled named `assignment`;

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS assignment (h_id bigint, country string, p_name string)
```

There is one row per `h_id`:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE assignment
  VALUES (19874, "France", "Example_Name"), 
         (21548, "France", "Example_Name"),
         (34569, "Germany", "Different_Name"),
         (47337, "Greece", "Another Name"),
         (54682, "Greece", "Example Name")
         (64963, "France", "Different Name");
```

I want to join `assignment` onto a second table, `state`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS state (id bigint, xml_id bigint, datetime_in string, datetime_out string)
```

`xml_id` is the join key with `h_id` and there are multiple rows per `h_id` in state.

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE state
  VALUES (1, 19874, "2014-04-03 10:38:31.0", "2017-11-30 10:45:00.0"), 
         (2, 19874, "2014-02-05 10:21:33.0", "2019-02-02 10:30:35.0"),
         (3, 19874, "2019-02-26 14:34:17.0", null),
         (4, 54682, "2019-03-07 14:43:34.0", null),
         (5, 54682, "2019-02-25 10:47:09.0", null)
         (6, 64963, "2019-02-06 12:50:05.0", "2019-05-04 16:15:08.0");
```

My desired output is the data from `assignment` with the most recent `datetime_in` from `state`.

Here is what I have tried:

```sql
SELECT xml_id, datetime_in
    FROM (SELECT *,
        dense_rank() over (partition by xml_id ORDER BY datetime_in DESC) as rank
        FROM state s
        WHERE s.xml_id IN (SELECT a.h_id FROM assignment a)
    ) temp
    WHERE rank = 1
```

The problem is that I only get ~2k rows back, despite there being ~7k rows in assignment.

If I do:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM state s
WHERE s.xml_id IN (SELECT a.h_id FROM assignment a)
```

I get ~8k results. I would expect that since there are multiple rows in `state` per `a.h_id`. However, I can't understand why I only get ~2k rows when trying to get the most recent `datetime_in` with the data from `assignment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some keys from `assignment` table do not exist in the `state` table, it seems only 2K keys exist in both tables.

Check also this query to find keys which exist only in assignment:

```
SELECT a.h_id 
  FROM assignment a 
       left join (select distinct s.xml_id from state s) s on  a.h_id =  s.xml_id
 WHERE s.xml_id is null;
```

If state table can contain many records with the same timestamp, then dense_rank will assign 1 to all records with the same timestamp, xml_id. If you need one record only, then use `row_number()`. If you need all records from assignment even if corresponding records do not exist in the state table, use `left join`. Replace `left join` with `inner join` if you need only keys existing in both tables:

```
select a.*, s.*
  from assignment a
       left join (SELECT s.*,
                        row_number() over (partition by xml_id ORDER BY datetime_in DESC) as rn
                   FROM state s
                 ) s on s.xml_id = a.h_id and s.rn=1
```

Comment: That gives a count of 5775. I guess 5775 is roughly the difference between my 2k and expected 8k. I also wanted to verify if my query is doing as intended? i.e. giving the correct timestamp per record. Hopefully I've done it correct and I just hadn't considered some missing keys.